# Why is my for loop only capturing y values of 699 instead of values ranging from 0 to 699?

Tags: python, pygame

I am programming an arcade game in pygame. I want every black pixel to be a walking surface for the player. I am trying to get_at every black pixel on screen and add it to a dict. Then, I want to compare the x and y coords of the player to the dict entries. When I print the dict Pixels, it only prints y=699 and x values range from 0 to 1250. How can I make walkable black surfaces by adding every black Pixel to a dict for comparison with player coords?

```
Pixels = {}

for x1 in range(0, 1250):
    for y2 in range(0, 700):
        xy12 = disp.get_at((x1, y2))
        if xy12[0] <= 3 and xy12[1] <= 3 and xy12[2] <= 3: #the <= just makes it so rgb values of 3 are close enough to black that it is acceptable...
             Pixels[x1] = y2

def pglc():
    global groundlim
    if playerx in Pixels:
        if playery == Pixels[playerx]:
            groundlim = playery

print Pixels
```

Answer (score 5):

This line is your problem

```
Pixels[x1] = y2
```

In the inner loop you are overwriting the value in each step, so the last value you see is `699` (but it had all the values from 0 to 698 before when the condition was met). You could make two dimensions:

```
Pixels[x1] = list()
```

And then in the inner loop:

```
Pixels[x1].append(y2)
```

In total:

```
Pixels = {}

for x1 in range(0, 1250):
    Pixels[x1] = list()
    for y2 in range(0, 700):
        xy12 = disp.get_at((x1, y2))
        if xy12[0] <= 3 and xy12[1] <= 3 and xy12[2] <= 3:
             Pixels[x1].append(y2)
```

Or - if you're into dict comprehensions (plus it uses `all(...)`):

```
Pixels = {x1:
              [y2 
               for y2 in range(0, 700) 
               for xy12 in [disp.get_at((x1, y2))]
               if (all(cond <= 3 for cond in xy12[0:2]))]
          for x1 in range(0, 1250)}
```

Comment: How can I fix this so all of the black pixel entries show up in the dict? This line is supposed to add the values to the dict

Comment: @PlasmodiumFalciparum: Updated the answer.

Comment: Will this still work? I ran the program and I still could not stand on black pixels:                            def pglc():
    global groundlim
    if playerx in Pixels:
        if playery == Pixels[playerx]:
            groundlim = playery

Answer (score 2):

as @Jan stated in his answer you are always changing the value of `Pixels[x1]`

In order to fix that you need to use an array that contains tuples (x, y). Remember that `dict.keys()` is a set, which means there cannot be any repeating objects

Comment: Using a list of tuples did not work when i tried it.

Comment: @PlasmodiumFalciparum what exactly have you tried? could you list some code? maybe there is a mistake in adding the tuples?

Comment: for x1 in range(0, 1250):
    for y2 in range(0, 700):
        xy12 = disp.get_at((x1, y2))
        if xy12[0] <= 3 and xy12[1] <= 3 and xy12[2] <= 3:
            Pixels.append(tuple(x1, y2))


def pglc():
    global groundlim
    if tuple(playerx, playery) in Pixels:
            groundlim = playery

Comment: It just does not work. It always returns True for some reason.

Comment: why do you use keyword tuple? you could simple use () for that

Comment: for x1 in range(0, 1250):
    for y2 in range(0, 700):
        xy12 = disp.get_at((x1, y2))
        if xy12[0] <= 3 and xy12[1] <= 3 and xy12[2] <= 3:
            Pixels.append((x1, y2))


def pglc():
    global groundlim
    if (playerx, playery) in Pixels:
            groundlim = playery

Comment: This code still does not let me stand on the black pixels

Comment: It still always returns True

Comment: Is there a better way instead of  if (playerx, playery) in Pixels: groundlim = playery to check if player coords are contained in the tuple list at a specific time?

Comment: Do you know how to check if player coords are exactly an entry in the tuple list?

Comment: @PlasmodiumFalciparum actually, `if (playerx, playery) in Pixels` should be working correctly. You could simply print the array `Pixels` in order to see which points are inside for debugging... maybe there is something wrong with `groundlim = playery`?

Comment: I think the problem is with 'if (playerx, playery) in Pixels' It always returns True. I ran a few tests and it returns True when i print it, regardless of player coords. Thus, it is constantly setting the ground limit to the player's y value, even as the player falls, so it becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure, the Pixels dict, is not suited for the problem, you store just one possible black Y for each X, while there could be more.

So here you get 699 for every x because it’s the last value of Y that was black.

Your data structure doesn’t allow for storing more than one black pixel per X coordinate.

You can either just store a set of tuples `Pixels = {}
 Pixels.add( (x, y))` that are black, and test if (x, y) in Pixels return True

Or you can store a set of Y coordinates for each X coordinate, so a dictionnary of sets.